# Error while connecting client.svc

Tags: sharepoint-server, odata

I am trying to connect client.svc and getting below error

"The server encountered an error processing the request. See server logs for more details."

ULS is giving below two error,

System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Data.Edm, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.  File name: 'Microsoft.Data.Edm, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'

System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Data.OData, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.  File name: 'Microsoft.Data.OData, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are missing WCF Data Services 5.0 for OData V3. Install it from here and reset IIS (may have to restart your machine):

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29306

I have seen this happening on dev machines having both Visual Studio 2012 and 2013 running side-by-side, and then uninstalling VS 2012 and related components.

Comment: Yes you are right. Sorry for not to updating the answer. This happen to me when i installed VS2013 and uninstall older version.